# Combining 2 Fields in one table for 43,000 records

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a code that i want to combine 2 fields from the same table to another field in the same table and also Fill in the StateName from another table

locations table has 43,000 records

I want to change this

```
Table: states_cache            Table: locations
StateName | StateInitials      LocationID |  City       | StateInitials | StateName | Combo
------------------------       --------------------------------------------------------------
Missouri  |  MO                32500      | Springfield | MO            |           |
Kansas    |  KS                34151      | Topeka      | KS            |           |
```

to This

```
Table: states_cache            Table: locations
StateName | StateInitials      LocationID |  City       | StateInitials | StateName | Combo
------------------------       --------------------------------------------------------------
Missouri  |  MO                32500      | Springfield | MO            | Missouri  | Springfield MO
Kansas    |  KS                34151      | Topeka      | KS            | Kansas    | Topeka KS
```

this is my code...

I try to run it and it just gives me the loading screen...

```
$conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();

$sql = "SELECT City, StateInitials, LocationID, StateInitials FROM locations";
            $rs = $conn->Execute($sql);

        while (!$rs->EOF)
            { 
                $sql2 = "SELECT StateName FROM states_cache WHERE StateInitials ='" . $rs->fields[3] . "'";
                $rs2 = $conn->Execute($sql2);
                if ($rs2 === false) die('select error: ' . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $sql2);

                $sql1 = "UPDATE locations SET StateName ='" . $rs2->fields[0] . "',  combo ='" . $rs->fields[0] . " " . $rs->fields[1] ."' where LocationID =" . $rs->fields[2];
                $rs1 = $conn->Execute($sql1);
                if ($rs1 === false) die('select error: ' . $conn->ErrorMsg() . " SQL: " . $sql1);
                echo $sql1;
            }

            ?>
```

-------------------SOLVED------------------------------

```
UPDATE locations 
  JOIN states_cache
    ON states_cache.StateInitials = locations.StateInitials
SET states_cache.StateName = locations.StateName, locations.Combo = CONCAT(locations.City, ' ', locations.StateInitials)
```

Thanks to Marc B for pointing me at an easier Solution

Comment: there is NO need to run these queries in a loop. You can do this with a single `update ... join` query.

Comment: Ok well i will research that

Comment: Thanks that was so MUCH easier....

Comment: UPDATE locations 
  JOIN states_cache
    ON states_cache.StateInitials = locations.StateInitials
SET states_cache.StateName = locations.StateName, locations.Combo = CONCAT(locations.City, ' ', locations.StateInitials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE locations 
  JOIN states_cache
    ON states_cache.StateInitials = locations.StateInitials
SET states_cache.StateName = locations.StateName, locations.Combo = CONCAT(locations.City, ' ', locations.StateInitials)
```